# List of functions that cannot be used in a parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have a problem using the Parallel Toolbox from Matlab. Indeed, I want to untar a series of archive in a parfor loop, and it seems that neither `untar` nor `system` are working. They do not cause an error, they simply do not produce any result.

The very same code works without any problem as soon as I deactivate the parallelism.

Is there a reference that lists the functions that cannot be used in `parfor` loops? I couldn't find it easily in the parallel toolbox documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` should work correctly inside a PARFOR loop - providing that the executable you invoke does not require user input.

```
>> matlabpool('size')
ans =
     3
>> parfor ii=1:2, system('pwd'), end
/tmp
ans =
     0
/tmp
ans =
     0
```

The main constraints on functions which cannot be used *directly* inside a PARFOR loop body relate to "workspace transparency" - you cannot use functions that modify the workspace such as `assignin`, `load`, `clear` etc. See [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bq__cs7-1.html) for more on that. (You can of course call a function from the body of a PARFOR loop which calls `load` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

function parallel_stuff

parfor i = 1:10

b = my_untar(a)

end

end

function b = my_untar(a)

b = untar(a)

end

Comment: I didn't try this specific example.  For a number of functions that can't run in parallel, they can in fact be called from a non parallel function that happens to be called in parallel.  I am not familiar with the untar command, but I don't see why it wouldn't work in this way (perhaps some other trickery is needed).  I was just pointing out that this way of wrapping a function before calling it sometimes works around the limitations with the parfor loops.